# ng-model value in multidimentional array

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am working in an application where i attach dynamic form attributes with parent element. Sample data will look like this

```
$scope.uploadedFiles = [{
   name: sample.jpg,
   attr: [{
        id: "caption",
        display: "Title",
        value: "",
        placeHolder: "Enter title",
        type: "textbox",
    },
    {
        id: "description",
        display: "Description",
        placeHolder: "Enter description",
        type: "textarea",
        rows: 8,
        value: "",
    }]
},
{
   name: sample2.jpg,
   attr: [{
        id: "caption",
        display: "Title",
        value: "",
        placeHolder: "Enter title",
        type: "textbox",
    },
    {
        id: "description",
        display: "Description",
        placeHolder: "Enter description",
        type: "textarea",
        rows: 8,
        value: "ttttt",
    }]
}]
```

In template i am using code like this

```
 <div  class="col-md-4" ng-repeat="item in uploadedFiles">
     <div style="padding:10px 4px;">
          <img class="{{photocss}}" style="width:100%; height:auto;" src="{{item.name}}" />
          <div ng-repeat="config in item.attr">
              <input ng-if="config.type=='textbox'" type="text" ng-blur="validate(config)" class="form-control" ng-model="config.value" placeholder="{{config.placeHolder}}"></input>
             <textarea ng-if="config.type=='textarea'" rows="config.rows" class="form-control"  ng-model="config.value" placeholder="{{config.placeHolder}}"></textarea>
        </div>
   </div>
```

When i run application and upload some files. list of uploaded photos appear along with dynamic attributes defined in array e.g Title and Description.

When i type something in Title, all titles updated, it shows ng-model bind with all title attributes even i defined attributes for each item (photo) in separate array.

Issue shown in attached screen:
[image]

In screen you will look, when i type test title, its populated with other element titles too. Can someone help my where i made mistake.

Also created plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/wruINbUYdarcxFYffJ0o?p=preview for issue that i am facing.

I want to put title with each element without conflicting with another element title.

Comment: I agree with @shershen. Your code seems to be working. Probably you just need to clear your browser history or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a plnkr here that works with you model structure: http://plnkr.co/edit/svR5Vz?p=preview and there no seem to be this effect. So probably error is in other part of your code.

Also using ng-switch could be a better option in this case, then ng-if:

```
<div ng-repeat="config in item.attr" ng-switch="config.type">
```

Comment: thanks for posting answer and your suggestion. will review the whole process which causes the issue. may be dynamically attaching form attributes with uploaded element may cause problem.

Comment: I created plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/wruINbUYdarcxFYffJ0o?p=preview, this is the issue i am facing. please check what i am doing wrong.

Comment: please check this one, seem to work correct for input field - if you add 'item.' to the model statement, http://plnkr.co/edit/buaAcQ2Y3IaqEtX92gus?p=preview

Comment: where you made changes, i followed your updated line of code but in my plnkr still same issue.